# sql can't figure out the query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contacts` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `providerId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `requestId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` binary(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fromuid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `touid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `sentdt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `readdt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `messagetext` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `device` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `live` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `authenticationTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `userKey` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IP` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `port` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `firstname` (`mobile`,`city`,`zip`)
)
```

And this SQL query that finds out friends/contacts for specified user (user id `1` in this case):

```
SELECT u.id
   ,u.mobile
   ,u.name
   ,(NOW() - u.authenticationTime) AS authenticateTimeDifference
   ,u.IP
   ,f.providerid
   ,f.requestid
   ,f.status
   ,u.port
FROM contacts f
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id =
IF (
      f.providerid = 1
      ,f.requestid
      ,f.providerid
      ) WHERE (
      f.providerid = 1
      AND f.status = 1
      )
   OR f.requestid = 1
```

That works fine but I want to be able to also join messages table and **show user's friends/contacts who have talked latest** (meaning latest conversations first) with `order by messages.sentdt desc` option but I am unable to figure out how to do that, I tried all joins but none worked :(

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

#### Update

Here is sample data above query returns:

[image]

In that **same** resultset, I want to be able to sort based on `order by messages.sentdt desc` but I am not sure how to pull that in and sort resultset by latest message first

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired result.

Comment: I meant the final result you are looking for with sample records from source tables it's derived from. Imagine that you hired someone else to write it. How would **you** make sure that they did a good job?

Comment: In that **same** resultset, I want to be able to sort based on `order by messages.sentdt desc` I dont know how to merge messages table posted in question and sort same result set based on `order by messages.sentdt desc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  select u.id
      , u.mobile
      , u.name
      , (NOW() - u.authenticationTime) as authenticateTimeDifference
      , u.IP
      , f.providerid
      , f.requestid
      , f.status
      , u.port
    from contacts f
    left join users u
      on u.id = if (f.providerid = 1, f.requestid, f.providerid)
    left join (select fromuid, max(sentdt) as sentdt from messages group by fromuid) m 
      on m.fromuid =  if (f.providerid = 1, f.providerid, f.requestid)
    where (f.providerid = 1 and f.status = 1) 
        or f.requestid = 1
    order by m.sentdt
```

Comment: It still doesn't sort by latest messages, may be order by with sentdt is not working ?? sentdt is timedate format

Comment: Sorry, I read the schema wrong the first time through, I'll post an edit in a few minutes.

Comment: sorting is still not right :( may be you want to create these tables and insert sample data and then test

Comment: I found the solution, thanks for letting me know how message table was needed to be plugged in. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Glad you found what you needed!